# How to call a public string from a @RemoteAction

Tags: apex, email, controller, email-template, remote-action

I have this apex code:

```
@RemoteAction
 public static Sample__c sample(){
    String rhtmlBody;
    rhtmlBody = htmlBody(emailtype, FirstName, LastName); 
}



public string htmlBody(String emailtype, String FirstName, String LastName){
     //Code . . . .
}
```

It has an error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: htmlBody(String, String, String)

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to make your htmlBody method as static because you can call static method only from static method.

```
@RemoteAction
public static Sample__c sample(){
String rhtmlBody;
rhtmlBody = htmlBody(emailtype, FirstName, LastName); 
}



public static string htmlBody(String emailtype, String FirstName, String LastName){
 //Code . . . .
}
```